# Custom streambuffer in std::ofstream

Tags: c++, io, streambuf

I know that in `std::ostream`, I can use a custom `streambuf` through either stating so in the constructor:

```
std::ofstream temp;
temp.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::in);
std::ostream example(temp.rdbuf());
```

as well as by setting it afterwards (same first two lines as before, but change the last line to:

```
std::ostream example;
example.rdbuf(temp.rdbuf());
```

My question is: How can I do that in `std::ofstream`? I want to be able to overwrite the methods `xsgetn` and `xsputn` implemented in `std::streambuf` in my own custom class and use this in my `ofstream`, but, short of writing my own custom `ofstream` am unsure of how to do so.

Comment: Maybe you meant How can I do that in std::streambuf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concrete file stream classes have their own `rdbuf()` method that takes  0 arguments and it *hides* the other `rdbuf()` method inherited from the virtual base `std::basic_ios`. Qualifying the name to lookup the base class method should work:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(example.rdbuf());
```